# Easily convert & archive a bunch of low res Video CD DAT files MPEG 1/2 to newer better format such as MKV or others?

Tags: conversion, file-formats

Each file is around 350-650 MB.

This is the media information from the Files:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBcWf.png

[image]

How could I better archive it?

Easily convert & archive a bunch of low res Video CD DAT files MPEG 1/2 to newer better format such as MKV or others?

Answer (score 5):

Using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, you can convert these DATs to MP4 (or MKV):

```
ffmpeg -i input.dat -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Your VLC output doesn't mention it but if the inputs are interlaced (likely), then use

```
ffmpeg -i input.dat -vf yadif -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say archive, do you mean for long-term storage, such as in a library or museum? If that's the case a lossless, well-documented, open-source codec and container is what you want. FFV1 in a matroska continer (.mkv file) is my preferred archival codec / container format, and it's gaining popularity in the [GLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLAM_(industry_sector)) sector.

Once again, FFMPEG is the tool of choice for making these–FFV1 is a codec developed by the creators of FFMPEG. A good page on how to encode FFV1 [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/FFV1), and an example would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.dat -c:a pcm_s16le -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -coder 1  -context  1  -g 1  output.mkv
```

For archival purposes I would *not* de-interlace because of the loss of resolution, and because it alters the source substantially.